# Why does LogisticRegressionCV's .score() differ from cross_val_score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I was using LogisticRegressionCV's `.score()` method to yield an accuracy score for my model.

I also used `cross_val_score` to yield an accuracy score with the **same cv split** (`skf`), expecting the same score to show up.

But alas, they were different and I'm confused.

I first did a StratifiedKFold:

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5,
                      shuffle = True,
                      random_state = 708)
```

After which I instantiated a LogisticRegressionCV() with the `skf` as an argument for the CV parameter, fitted, and scored on the training set.

```
logreg = LogisticRegressionCV(cv=skf, solver='liblinear')

logreg.fit(X_train_sc, y_train)
logreg.score(X_train_sc, y_train)
```

This gave me a score of 0.849507735583685, which was accuracy by default. Since this is LogisticRegressionCV, this score is actually the mean accuracy score right?

Then I used `cross_val_score`:

```
cross_val_score(logreg, X_train_sc, y_train, cv=skf).mean()
```

This gave me a mean accuracy score of 0.8227814439082044.

I'm kind of confused as to why the scores differ, since I thought I was basically doing the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [`.score`] is actually the mean accuracy score right?

No. The `score` method here is the accuracy score of the final classifier (which was retrained on the entire training set, using the optimal value of the regularization strength). By evaluating it on the training set again, you're getting an optimistically-biased estimate of future performance.

To recover the cross-validation scores, you can use the attribute `scores_`.  Even with the same folds, these *may* be slightly different from `cross_val_score` due to randomness in the solver, if it doesn't converge completely.

Comment: HI Ben, was looking through some old questions I asked, and realised I did not select your response as answer. Once again, thank you for your reply, it was very helpful, and I'm sure it has also benefitted others.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer, you can change the behaviour of your code by simply adding "refit = False" as a parameter to LogisticRegressionCV(), e.g.

```
logreg = LogisticRegressionCV(cv=skf, solver='liblinear', refit=False)
```

the rest you can keep the same.